# How to make MultiCheckBox Label bold or strong?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-form2

I have the following multicheckbox:

```
   $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',

        'name' => 'directPractice',
        'options' => array(
           'label' => 'A. Check all direct practice field education assignments',

         **EDIT 1:**
         'label_attributes' => array(
                'class'  => 'label-multicheckbox-group'
            ),


            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class' => 'OnlineFieldEvaluation\Entity\FieldEducationAssignments', //'YOUR ENTITY NAMESPACE'
            'property' => 'directPractice', //'your db collumn name'
            'value_options' => array(
                '1' => 'Adults',
                '2' => 'Individuals',
                '3' => 'Information and Referral',
                '4' => 'Families',
            ),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => '1', //set checked to '1'
            'multiple' => true,
        )
    ));
```

How to make the following part bold?
Using label_attributes makes all labels bold, and I want just the main label for the multibox be bold.

```
'label' => 'A. Check all direct practice field education assignments',
```

**EDIT 1: add label_attributes to "options"**

When I add label_attributes as @itrascastro suggested, all labels become bold and I want only the top one to become bold: [multicheckbox](http://take.ms/qZYVa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no build in option to do this just for the top label, I used jQuery to accomplish this:

```
$("label[for]").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("label-bold");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your options:

```
'options'    => array(
    'label_attributes' => array(
        'class'  => 'myCssBoldClass'
    ),
    // more options
),
```

Comment: I tried it before. It makes all labels bold and I want only the top one to become bold. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Each value option [accepts an array of options](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L161).

For example

```
'value_options' => [
    [
        'label' => 'Adults',
        'label_attributes' => [
            'class' => 'my-bold-class',
        ],
        'attributes' => [],
        'value' => 1,
        'selected' => false,
        'disabled' => false,
    ],
    '2' => 'Individuals',
    '3' => 'Information and Referral',
    '4' => 'Families',
],
```

I've added in some other values you can define; they are obviously optional.

Comment: Yep, but how do I make only the top one bold, and other regular ? Notice how they are all in bold if I define it for the top one: http://take.ms/RSCsP

Comment: Have you removed the bold class from the main `label_attributes`? If you define it as I have shown the class should only be applied to the `Adults` option.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not clear. I want it only to be applied for this option:
"A. Check all direct practice field education assignments"

Comment: Right, I understand now. Obviously you would normally follow @itrascastro answer, however if you do so, it looks like the attributes  [are merged in as 'global label attributes' to each value option](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L170) making any bold class display for all options as well. This means there is no out of the box way to do what you want, you would need to extend the class and override the `renderOptions` method to prevent it.

Comment: If it is so, then other option would be to define label_attributes  for each value_option to override global "bold" effect .